# How to remove duplicate entries in PHP's mysqli_query return value?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm using the following code to retrieve data from my MySQL DB

```
function mySqlQueryToArray($sql){
    $con = mysqli_connect(host, user, pw, db); //I've ommitted the access details for security

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      exit("ERROR: Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // Process SQL query
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    // Put result  into 2D array
    $output = array();
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        array_push($output, $row);
    }

//Finish
    mysqli_close($con);
    return $output;
}
```

The return value of this function looks something like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [TopicID] => 1
            [1] => test
            [name] => test
        )

)
```

I'd like to make it so that the output instead looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [TopicID] => 1
            [name] => test
        )

)
```

I'm wondering A) Why the function creates these duplicates and B) How to remove them, either as part of the call to mysqli_query or as some array manipulation magic.

Comment: When reviewing the above duplicate question just keep in mind yo use the mysqli equivelant of the mysql functions

Comment: Behavior of **`mysqli_fetch_array`** is documented here: [http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)

Comment: @JohnConde: I don't think it's wise to close mysqli questions with the deprecated API equivalents. on the long term you want mysqli answers.... just let users build the answers that can be used as dupes.